# Structure of main menu

Tags: 7, routes

I have HTML menu. With the following:

```
<li><a href="#">cccc</a></li>
<li><a href="#">aaaaaa</a></li>
<li><a href="#">bbbb</a></li>
```

And created this items on Main Menu via Drupal admin. I know, when erase this HTML items and add `?php print render($page['main_menu']); ?>` get my menu structure. But i don't want it.

I want, my Drupal menu items, write `a href=**` So, like this:

```
<li><a href="php print render($page['main_menu_cccc_item']); ?>">cccc</a></li>
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to achieve a little bit more? What do you want the final markup to look like?

Comment: no point in using drupal menu then?